# Moving buttons in android

Tags: android, animation, button, marquee

I need to move a few buttons horizontally.These buttons are dynamically created.
My present code is

```
 TranslateAnimation  mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
                        TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1f,
                        TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.2f,
                        TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
                        TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f
                       );
               mAnimation.setDuration(15000);
               mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
               mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
               mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
               mAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

                LinearLayout alertlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.alertll);
                alertlayout.startAnimation(mAnimation);
```

And then dynamically create buttons and add to this linear layout. But all the buttons are not displaying. Since the width of this linear layout is screen width, it displays only the button that can be filled in the screen width.

How can I fix this?

Comment: you need to add your LinearLayour in ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to animate the parent layout. You need your buttons(child views) to animate. right?.

Create a `AnimationSet` that contains animation objects for each button.

Comment: Tried this.. But no use.. same prob